# manipulate the video speed in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in flutter and work on a certain project in which I need to record a video from the mobile camera. for that, I used a camera plugin. but there is one thing I need in this that the user can manipulate the video speed frame in both at the recording time and also if the video is already recorded. but it's more than one day, I didn't find any library to do such a requirement.can anyone help me with this to achieve in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not even physically possible to change recording speed while recording (Your camera should know about future to do that)! But for a recorded video you can use `flutter_ffmpeg` library from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg). Below is a `ffmpeg` command which can change video speed:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" output.mkv
```

This command will double the speed of `input.mkv` and will save it as `output.mkv`

Comment: hi, @Amir_P conversion comand is right , but it is too slow and takes very much time. can we make it faster.

Comment: @AnkitMishra I'm not expert in video encoding and ffmpeg but I think that depends on a lot of things like hardware, encoding format, quality. You can change some of them and speed things up.